# How to call UIViewController's transitionFromViewController in Swift?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift

How should I implement this method call with Swift?

```
[containerViewController transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                                         toViewController:toViewController
                                                 duration:0.2
                                                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                               animations:nil
                                               completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                   [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                                                   [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:containerViewController];
                                                   toViewController.view.frame = containerViewController.view.bounds;
                                               }];
```

====

```
    containerViewController.transitionFromViewController(
        fromViewController,
        toViewController,
        0.2,
        UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve,
        nil,
        nil)
```

I get this error: Use of unresolved identifier 'UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve'

Comment: Do you have Xcode code completion off?

Comment: code completion is set ON

Comment: For the animations use UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve

Comment: enums are (finally!) namespaced in Swift :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working solution:

```
containerViewController.transitionFromViewController(
            fromViewController,
            toViewController: toViewController,
            duration: 0.2,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
            nil,
            completion: { finished in
                fromViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
                toViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(containerViewController)
                toViewController.view.frame = containerViewController.view.bounds
            })
```

Comment: before calling remove you should call willMoveToParentViewController(nil) according to the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Write `.TransitionCrossDissolve` instead of `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`. The type `UIViewAnimationOption` is known by the method which makes it possible to be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
containerViewController.transition(from: fromViewController,
                                   to: toViewController,
                                   duration: 0.2,
                                   options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                                   nil,
                                   completion: { _ in
                                    fromViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
                                    toViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: containerViewController)
                                    toViewController.view.frame = containerViewController.view.bounds
})
```